# Python - ограничение выдачи генератором по количеству элементов

Tags: python, генераторы

Вопрос сугубо технический
Дефолтно генератор [x for x in list if f()] вернет все элементы из множества list соответствующие условию f(). Мне необходимо ограничить эту выдачу по количеству, что бы было, например, не более 10 элементов на выходе.

Дело вот какое, насколько я понимаю если в f() забита какая-нибудь интересная формула, то генератор совершит эту операцию некоторое множество раз, при объеме списков в 10 000, будет произведено 10 000 операций, в то время как мне они ну вот совершенно не нужны.

Пока в голову приходит только написание отдельной функции обработки множества, но это получается на каждый генератор(а их у меня очень много) - придется писать свою функцию.

В общем вопрос еще раз - как ограничить объем выдачи генератора. Может как то можно прикрутить каунтер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
list(itertools.islice((x for x in list if f()), 10))
#                     ------------------------
```

Обратите внимание что квадратные скобки вокруг вашего выражения стали круглыми. Это генератор, он ленивый. `f` будет вызываться только до тех пор как вернёт `True` десять раз, не более.

**P.S.** Квадратные скобки - не [генератор](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) (который ленивый), а [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (который жадный).

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!